# Converting String to Integers R

Tags: r, string

I am doing something which should be quite simple. I would like to convert a vector of charter string to unique integers. From researching how to do this I found the stroi function which claims to convert strings to integers. However, I am getting weird results and I cannot understand why. When I run the code in the documentation below it works fine:

```
strtoi(c("ffff", "FFFF"), 16L)
[1] 65535 65535
```

However, when I apply this function to actually data I get a vector of NAs. Consider the following example:

```
strtoi(c('spy','spx'),16L)
[1] NA NA
```

Why does it return NAs in this example? Is there a way to get strtoi to work or do I need to write my own function?

Comment: `strtoi` is for converting, e.g., hexadecimal strings to the decimal integers they represent. Converting any old string to unique integers is usually done with `factor`, as in `as.integer(factor(x))`.

Comment: Are spy and spx the names of variables that contain the strings you want to convert?

Answer (score 0):

in

```
strtoi(c("ffff", "FFFF"), 16L)
[1] 65535 65535
```

you are converting Hexa string to numbers

in this case

```
strtoi(c('spy','spx'),16L)
[1] NA NA
```

S, p, y and x are out of the HEXA spectrum....
thats why you get NA

if you try another base it might work... for instance

```
strtoi(c('spy','spx'),36L)
[1] 37222 37221
```